# Setting up ASP.NET website on IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I'm moving a site from IIS6 on Server 2003 to IIS7 Sever 2008.

Its pretty much a .NET 3.5 basic app, nothing special.

I've never used IIS 7 before, and i can't even get an html page running under the assigned ip.

Can someone provide simple, step by step instructions, for just setting up a website that was previulsy on IIS 6, on IIS 7?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to acess the static HTML file from the server itself. If it works on the server, but not from a client machine, I suspect some Windows firewall issues.

I would also check if all necessary components needed to run IIS are installed. For security reasons a Windows Server 2008 standard installation  most of the services which are commonly installed on a Windows Server 2003.

So, in order to make IIS and ASP.NET work, check your "Server Roles" or follow this tutorial on IIS.net: [Installing IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis-70-on-windows-server-2008/).